# iOS update ui from for loop with OpenGL draw commands

Tags: ios, for-loop, opengl-es

I am writing an iOS drawing application. 
I have a for loop with OpenGL drawing commands inside.
Now I have to update some UI in the for loop with every some steps;

But the problem is that both OpenGL commands and UI updating codes should be run in the main thread. all UI updating codes are run until the for loop is completed.

Is there any way to solve the problem to delay the for loop for ui to update?

Updated:

```
//flood fill 
for (int i = 0; i < width; i += FloodFillStep) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j += FloodFillStep) {
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(i, j);            
        GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(4 * sizeof(GLubyte));
        // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
        glReadPixels(point.x, point.y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        if (data[3] != 0) {
            free(data);
            continue;
        }
        free(data);

        unsigned int byteIndex = (self.maskData.bytesPerRow * roundf(point.y)) + roundf(point.x) * self.maskData.bytesPerPixel;
        unsigned long int maskIndex =  getMaskCode(byteIndex, self.maskData.maskIndexData);

        if ([dic valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", maskIndex]]) {
            continue;
        }

        [dic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", maskIndex]];

        [[REGLWrapper current] bindFramebufferOES:self.brushTexture.frameBuffer discardHint:true clear:true];

        const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(self.autoFillColorSystem.resultColor.CGColor);
        glClearColor(components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        self.brush.brushState.maskIndex = [ACFloodFill maskIndexWithMaskData:self.maskData atPoint:point];

        [[REGLWrapper current] bindFramebufferOES:self.curPaintedLayerTexture.frameBuffer discardHint:true clear:false];

        [self drawQuad:self.VAOQuad brush:self.brush.brushState texture2D:self.brushTexture.texID alpha:1.0];

        //            [self updateFinalRender];
    }

    DebugLog(@"autoFloodfill updateUIBlock percent %.2f", (CGFloat)i / (CGFloat)width * 100);
    if (updateUIBlock) {
        updateUIBlock((CGFloat)i / (CGFloat)width * 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: it sounds like you are doing things really weirdly. what exactly happens each step of your for loop? rendering code should be done in an event loop that would trigger once per screen refresh, so it seems like your for loop would be doing redundant drawing. maybe post some code to help us get an idea what your are trying to do

Comment: Render loops are complex things.  Have you read the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) on the subject?

Comment: I have posted my code. I am working on a flood fill function for my drawing app. because the process takes some time, so I want to update the ui to nortify user with the percentage of completion.

Comment: Are you doing glReadPixels() from current framebuffer and just after that you render something to the same framebuffer ? This is very bad practice ...